# Details on Selenium ChromeDriver options

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Here is my code:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication11
{
public partial class Form1 : Form // Se declara driver, variables.
{

    public  IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver()

    public Form1() // Se inicia Form y se minimiza cmd
    {

        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

And I can't set ChromeOptions to the WebDriver, and I want to change the Start Page of the driver (it starts on "data:,").

If I try to put ChromeOptions over or above of:

```
 public  IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

It doesn't let me cause "driver" doesn't exist.

I wish I could post the entire CODE but I'm not allowed, so if this isn't ok, make me know.

Some help?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the instantiation in the loading method of the form. Here you can also create the options and give them to the webdriver :

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    ...
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
}
```